How to copy and paste pixels in an image
Consider the image texture below:

Is it possible to select an area of the image and copy and paste it?
For instance:


There isn't a way to do this in the Image Editor as is done in the dedicated image editors outside of Blender. In Photoshop, you would use a magic wand or a marquee tool to make a selection and then duplicate to a new layer and move it about.
Blender is first concerned with geometry and drawing the mesh and then including the pixels of the texture on that mesh, so anything pixel related has to be solved through geometry.
If you bring your image texture into the 3d view as an Image Plane with shadeless or emission shader options, you can set up an orthographic camera to the same pixels as your image and adjust the Orthographic scale until the full image is in view. Then you can do a really neat trick of making a duplicate of your image plane and subdivide it such that you can select the faces that make up the part of the texture you want to duplicate and delete the remainder of the faces. You can then move it around in Object mode and place the duplicate where you want, as well as use an Array Modifier on it or any other thing you can imagine.
Your camera can then render to a new image that you can save as an iteration of that original texture.
I built a workflow around this topic and got help setting up an addon to do it called Draw2Paint. The idea to eventually improve the Image Editor to do this as other editors do is already posted on RightClickSelect dot com, but if you want to look for it and give it and upvote maybe later when the Devs are working on image editing and painting they will see the enthusiasm for it.
edit: I stripped out the Image2CanvasPlus into its own addon so you can quickly set up from the image editor to the 3d view with matching camera. https://github.com/artistCDMJ/Image2CanvasPlus/tree/main

To add to Craig's answer, for your particular case, a workaround would be to use the Clone brush as Stencil in Texture Paint mode in the 3D view (in Orthographic mode) and select a copy of your image as texture, but the easiest solution is to use an image editor like Krita.

